# Access php form from a web server in java and get results

Tags: java

There is a website with a form (`form.php`) where I fill some information and I get a result on another page (`search.php`) P.S. action of the form is `POST`.

Is it possible to write an application in `Java` to pass values to `search.php` on that web server and then parse the `HTML` file with the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a small application which makes use of [`Selenium`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Selenium is a web testing automation framework which allows applications (it includes a Java Wrapper) to interact with web sites.

You can then make use of Selenium to parse the result of the POST.